# Customizing rss feed in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new with wordpress. I want to customize my rss feeds. But I couldn't find the rss file.

I want to change this rss: http://goo.gl/KEiS0U

I tried to change `wp-includes/feed-rss2.php` and `wp-includes/feed-rss.php`

But they don't change. It is not working. Where can I change this rss feed?

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit CORE WordPress files like the one you are editing now. WordPress provides hooks to do whatever you want ( well almost ) without touching the core.

[See this on how to modify the RSS feed with a template](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/)

[This also shows you how to write and use your own template](http://gregrickaby.com/custom-rss-template-wordpress/)

[This is what the Codex says about RSS Feed modifications](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds)

If you prefer using a plugin ( In the WP world, in most cases what you want is already done by someone before you )

Check this out : https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/custom-feed